# Read the text of the Cell instead of Value

Tags: c#, excel, text

I am trying to write a program to compare two excel files in C#. 
I am able to open the files n read the value of the excel but i would like to compare the text in the Cell.

For example In my sheet, If the Cell A3 is having a formula say "=A1+A2". I am able to retrieve the value using

```
((Range)worksheet.Cells[2,0]).Value
```

of A3(the total value of A1 and A2) but not "=A1+A2". How can i get the text.(.Text is always null)

Thanks you

Comment: please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the Formula property should have it.

[Range.Formula Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.formula.aspx)

"If the cell contains a constant, this property returns the constant. If the cell is empty, this Formula property returns an empty string. If the cell contains a formula, the Formula property returns the formula as a string in the same format that would be displayed in the formula bar (including the equal sign)."

```
((Range)worksheet.Cells[2,0]).Formula;
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
((Range)worksheet.Cells[2,0]).Formula
```

MSDN reference see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.formula.aspx