# Extract data from cell

Tags: c#

The following code works fine , it extracts data from all cells in a sheet

```
using (OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    string query = string.Format("SELECT  * FROM [{0}]", sheetName);
    con1.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con1);
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {
            con.Open();
            for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 1; j < dt.Columns.Count; j ++)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString());
                 }
             }
         }
```

The code above extract data in the green rectangle but I need to extract data in the red rectangle in the following picture .

[image]

How could I extract data in the rectangle not in the green rectangle  ?

Comment: Can you change the format of the column?

Comment: @TaW I can't do any changement in the excel file .

Comment: Can you try this and tell me if it works: MessageBox.Show(Double.Parse(dt.Rows[i][j].Value));

Comment: @TaW I am not using NPOI .

Comment: @Gnqz there is an error in dt.Rows[i][j].Value

Comment: what does dt.Rows[i][j].GetType().FullName return?

Comment: Pardon, it should be dt.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value, if my memory serves me correct...

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419987/read-the-text-of-the-cell-instead-of-value)?

Comment: @EmanueleGreco It returns system.string

Comment: Are you shore? I'm asking dt.Rows[i][j].GetType().FullName not dt.Rows[i][j].Value.GetType().FullName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the displayed digits by changing region and setting in the control panel, this way full values will be displayed which can be fetched by OLEDB connection. 
EDIT:
After reading your commment abount not changing excel cell column format I will suggest trying EPPLUS.